# How to append a "sub"struct to a list in go

Tags: go, data-structures, struct

```
type A struct {
  B []struct {
    C string
    D []struct {
      E string
      F []struct {
        G string
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Lets say I have an instance of struct A, and I want to 
append a struct D into it. I would try to do something like

```
var a A;
...
a.B.D = append(a.B.D, ???)
```

??? = A.B.D

--> type A has no method B

??? = D

--> undefined: D

--- Edit for more complete example ---

```
type A struct {
  B []struct {
    C string
    D hugeNestedElement
  }
}

var a A
// Goal is to create many B's
a = append(a, what_goes_here)
// or ...
a = append(a.B, what_goes_here)
```

Comment: Can you give a more complete example?  Is this all of the code?

Comment: Appending a D to A is not correct to say.  You are really choosing a B to append a D to.  There may be many Bs since A.B is a slice of structs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `B` is a slice of structs, it has no `D` attribute directly.  There could be a variable number of `B`'s:

```
type A struct {
  B []struct {
    C string
    D []struct {
      E string
      F []struct {
        G string
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Since `B` is a slice the entry below assumes you'd like to append a new `D` to the first `B`:

```
A.B[0].D = append(A.B[0].D, anotherD)
```

Comment: How would you create `anotherD`, given you have `E string` and `G string`?

Comment: @CharlieGetzen You will have to create new anonymous struct definitions in the `append()`, e.g. `a.B = append(a.B, struct{ C string }{"value"})`. It's cumbersome and a good reason to avoid anonymous structs in cases like this, especially if it's more complex than just one or two simple fields.

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I was looking for. I'm assuming it would be recommended to split out that struct and reference it by name instead of nesting?